# Ruby: How to save user defined logic in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to store `AND` `OR` logic with details in a db table, and I'm using activerecord and Postgres.

This is a simplified example:

I have a table called `FulfillmentRules` that contains the following fields:

```
order_element #like product
element_detail #like color
is_equal_to
```

And a user can create a logical statement like: IF **product** is_equal_to **blue** then do something..

However, they can also create additional levels of this logic. So instead of just one line, then can add logical operators **AND / OR**

So the user generated logic could be the following:
IF **product** **color** is_equal_to **blue** AND **product** **size** is_equal_to **large** do something

My `FulfillmentRules` table can capture the details, but the problem is somehow also storing the logic.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There is no single answer since it is a question about recommendation. Usually in cases like yours there is some kind of micro-language in a project that used to write user-defined logic as a code, then this code stored in the database usually as JSON AST. Stripe and Shopify discount logics as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you constrain the flexibility of filtering logic with the options available in the UI, I would create a model called, say, FilterRule, where:

```rb
class FulfillmentRule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :filter_rules
end

class FilterRule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fulfillment_rule
  # has fields called fulfillment_rule_id, filter_attribute, filter_value, filter_logic, chaining_logic
end
```

so an instance of FulfillmentRule might have associated filter_rule records

```
fulfillment_rule_id, filter_attribute, filter_value, filter_logic, chaining_logic
1,                   product_color,    blue,         equal_to,     and
1,                   product_color,    green,        equal_to,     or
1,                   product_size,     large,        equal_to,     and
```

It's a little DSL for the small example you are asking about. Not the kind of DSL that a large ecommerce site might use.

Comment: This might work.. just thinking out loud.. maybe the first rule would have chaining_logic as blank and the subsequent rules would have the chaining_logic.. so it would read rule #1 + chaining_logic of rule #2 + rule #2 etc

Comment: good point, I agree